# GoogleMock issue building C++ simple code with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, googlemock

In MobileTest.h i have:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
using ::testing::Return;

#include "Mobile.h"

class MockedCamera : public Camera {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(ON, bool());
    MOCK_METHOD0(OFF,bool());
};
```

Mobile.h code:

```
#ifndef __MOBILE_H__
#define __MOBILE_H__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Camera.h"

class Mobile {
private:
    Camera *pCamera;
public:
    Mobile();
    Mobile(Camera *pCamera);
    bool powerOn();
    bool powerOff();
    virtual ~Mobile(){};
};

#endif /* __MOBILE_H__ */
```

Camera.h header file

```
#ifndef __CAMERA_H__
#define __CAMERA_H__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Camera {
public:
    Camera();
    virtual bool ON();
    virtual bool OFF();
    virtual ~Camera(){};
};

#endif /* __CAMERA_H__ */
```

This is a simple code of Udemy C++ Course but when building with eclipse it gives me errors no mobile test.h MOCK_METHOD0 macro call:

```
Symbol 'ArgumentCount' could not be resolved
The type 'testing::internal::FunctionMocker' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'testing::internal::UntypedFunctionMockerBase::UntypedPerformAction'
```

This is the makefile of the project and it gives me lots of error gtest related when i try to use make command:

```
SRC = $(wildcard src/*.cpp test/*.cpp)

OBJS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14

LIBS = -pthread libgtest.a

INC = -I googletest/googletest \
      -I googletest/googletest/include \
      -I googlemock/googlemock \
      -I googlemock/googlemock/include \
      -I src \
      -I test

EXE = mobileTest.exe

all: $(OBJS)
    cp -f $(OBJS) .
    g++-7 -o $(EXE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(INC)
    rm -f $(OBJS)

%.o: %.cpp
    g++-7 -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.exe
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I had a similar issue with indexer, when I had incorrectly linked GoogleMock to the project (IIRC I had some old GoogleMock somewhere). Check your project settings if the valid GTest/GMock libraries are linked to your project.

Comment: I added gtest, gtest_main, gmock, gmock_main and usr/local/lib like path but nothing

Answer (score 0):

I use gtest and gmock as library.

The project file of gtest library contains the following source files

```
SOURCES += ../googletest/src/gtest.cc \
../googletest/src/gtest-death-test.cc \
../googletest/src/gtest-filepath.cc \
../googletest/src/gtest-port.cc \
../googletest/src/gtest-printers.cc \
../googletest/src/gtest-test-part.cc \
../googletest/src/gtest-typed-test.cc
```

The project file of gmock library contains the following source files

```
SOURCES += ../googlemock/src/gmock-cardinalities.cc \
       ../googlemock/src/gmock-internal-utils.cc \
       ../googlemock/src/gmock-matchers.cc \
       ../googlemock/src/gmock-spec-builders.cc \
       ../googlemock/src/gmock.cc
```